# How to show the cardinality $0$ is less than the cardinality $1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I know that to show this I have to show there’s an injection from the $\varnothing$ to $\{\varnothing\}$.
But how can one even define a function on the $\varnothing$?

Comment: What's the definition of a function?

Comment: A mapping from one set to another

Comment: No, the formal definition.

Comment: Of course, it is the empty function; $\;\varnothing\times\{\varnothing\}$ is the empty set.

Comment: Recall the definition of "function from $X$ to $Y$": A set $f\subset X\times Y$ such that for every $x\in C$ there exists exactly one  $y\in Y$ with $(x,y)\in f$. It follows that if $A$ is any set then $\emptyset$ is an injective function from $\emptyset$ to  $A$.

Comment: Formally, a function f from a set X to a set Y is defined by a set G of ordered pairs (x, y) such that x ∈ X, y ∈ Y, and every element of X is the first component of exactly one ordered pair in G.

Comment: But if $X$ = emptyset then there is no $x \in X$

Comment: In the past I thought there exists a unique  $f:A \rightarrow {1}$ defined by $a \rightarrow 1$ for all $a \in A$ where $A$ is non-empty set. Does the emptyset function mean I am wrong and that $f$ is not unique.

Comment: No, you're right. A function on A has to contain an ordered pair with first element a for each a in A, so there's no "empty function" on a non empty set. But there is an empty function on the empty set.

Comment: "But if X = emptyset then there is no x∈X" EXACTLY!   So for any $b \in Y$ there is no $(x,b) \in \emptyset \times Y$.  And if there are $0$ such $(x,b)$ then there can not be more than one! So $\emptyset: \emptyset \to Y$ is injective because for every $y \in Y$ there is at most one (in fact there are zero) $(x,y) \in \emptyset \subset \emptyset \times Y$.

Comment: "In the past I thought there exists a unique f:A→1 defined by a→1 **for all** a∈A where A is non-empty set. "  And that is true **FOR ALL** $a\in \emptyset$.  That is trivially and vacuously true for all $a \in \emptyset$ because there aren't *ANY* $a\in \emptyset$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function, $f:X\to Y$ is a subset of a cartesian product, $X\times Y$ where each element $a \in X$ is "represented" precisely once.

$h:\emptyset \to \{\emptyset\} \subseteq \emptyset \times \{\emptyset\} = \{(x,y)|x \in \emptyset, y \in \{\emptyset\}\}$.  But as $\emptyset$ is empty $x \in \emptyset$ is impossible so so $\emptyset \times \{\emptyset\} = \{(x,y)|x \in \emptyset, y \in \{\emptyset\}\} = \emptyset$.

So $h= \emptyset$.  Is $\emptyset$ injective?  What does that mean?

$f\subseteq X\times Y$ is injective if for any $b\in Y$ there is at most one $(x,b)\in f$.

So for any $b \in \{0\}$ how many $(x, b) \in h = \emptyset$.  Well, zero as $h$ is empty.  So is there at most one?  Well, there sure as heck aren't *more* than one!

....

The emptyset is always an empty function from $\emptyset \to $ any set $X$ and it is vacuously injective.

Vacuous statements are, admittedly, irritating and confusing and you have my empathy.  If it helps, you can put a mental close in most definitions as "An $x$ is GLOOP if *when it exists* GOBBLETY occurs.  *And when it doesn't exist it is GLOOP by default*.  That's kind of cheating but it helps.

The old stumbling block is "Every element in the emptyset is red".  That is true.  Every element of the emptyset, all zero of them, *are* red because there aren't *any* elements.  But if we say "Every element in the emptyset, *if it exists*, is red" that's very clear.  Unfortunately it's inaccurate because the element *doesn't* exist.... well, it's still technically accurate to say it is red.... *sigh*... it gets easier.

Althernatively,  Every element is GLOOP $\iff $ there is no element that is *not* GLOOP.  It's very clear that the RHS is always true for an emptyset as there no elements at all.

Comment: What’s confusing me is my definitions of injectivity have always involved elements in the domain... of which there aren’t any now!

Comment: Why have you written h to be a proper subset in line 3?

Comment: Right.... but that makes *all* (postive) statements vacuously true.  "If $a \in \emptyset$ then $a$ is GLOOP."  That *must* be true because 1) a false hypothesis ($a\in \emptyset $ is always false) leads to *any* conclusion, and 2) there is not counterexample:  There are no $a\in \emptyset$ where $a$ *isn't GLOOP. ... admittedly empty functions are hard to imaging but... well think of it like this... there aren't any elements of $\emptyset$ that *aren't* being mapped to $Y$ so all elements of $\emptyset$ *are* being mapped to $Y$...

Comment: "Why have you written h to be a proper subset in line 3?"  Notation varies by from person to person and text to text but, I, me, fleablood, do not consider $\subset$ to mean proper subset.  If I wish to indicate proper subset, I would write $\subsetneq$.  However, if I were writing in pen, if a wanted subset possibly not proper, I'd write $\subseteq$.  But when I write in mathjax, I think "subset" so I write \$\subset\$ which comes out $\subset$.  Sorry if that is confusing.

Comment: That’s ok. One more question. Is the function from the empty set to the emptyset then injective also by your reasoning

Comment: Yes..... $h: \emptyset \to Y = \emptyset$ is an injective (empty) function for all $Y$.  Even if $Y = \emptyset$.  Worth noting that $h: \emptyset \to Y$ is *never* surjective (obviously) *unless* $Y$ is empty.  Then $h: \emptyset \to \emptyset $ is bijective (vacuously).

Comment: This is hard to understand but thanks.

Comment: @Anteater23. I've tried an explanation below, with an emphasis on the logical aspect of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

General idea: in order 2 conditions to be both satisfied, it is already necessary the first one to be satisfied.

So if non-injectivity requires 2 conditions and if the first one cannot be satisfied, non-injectivity does not hold , and therefore, automatically , injectivity holds.

---

Let f be a function from  {  }  to  { {  } }.

Let me " define" f arbitrarily like this : for all x, f(x) = 2x.

Now, whatever its " definition" may be, f is a relation, and therefore, in this case, a subset of the cartesian product :

```
                 "{  }  cross { {  } }"
```

that is , the set of all pairs (x,y) such that (1) x belongs to Empty Set and (2)  y belongs to { {  }  }.

But, ***since condition (1) cannot be satisfied, a fortiori, there is no pair that satisfies both conditions***, so my cartesian product is the Empty set.

I know that function f, that is a relation,  is a subset of a cartesian product that is empty. But the only subset of the empty set is the empty set itself. ***So : function f such that f(x)=2x is identical to the Empty set.***

( That would have been true whatever formula I would have used to  "define" f).

Now, ***is f injective?***

I know that f is injective just in case :

***IF*** a pair (a, c) belongs to f ( whatever this pair may be)  , ***THEN*** there is no pair ( b, c) belonging to f with element *a* different from  element *b*.

( indeed, if we had at the same time (a, c) and ( b,c) with *a* different from *b*, then 2 diffetent elements of the domain would have the same image, and *f* would not be injective).

You know that ***a statement of the form (P --> Q) is false just in case P is true and Q is false***. Let's apply this logical fact to our definition of injectivity which is an IF...THEN statement.

***Let's see whether it is possible for f not to be injective.***

***For f NOT to be injective*** , it would be required that :

(1) there is actually a pair (a, b) belonging to f [ this is the " P is true" part]

AND

(2) there *is* ( at least) a pair (b, c) belonging to f with a different from b  [ this is the "Q is false" part, for, remember, Q was " there is *no* pair..." ]

But it is impossible that both consitions hold, ***since it is already impossible the first one to hold:*** f being empty, there is no pair (a,c)  that belongs to f, since there is nothing that belongs to f.

So ***the proposition " f is NOT injective" is FALSE*** ( and even necessarily false).

Consequently, the proposition " f is injective" must be true.